# Does Score API require publish_actions or publish_stream?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-applications, permissions, facebook-apps

Currently, I hae email and publish_actions under User & Friend Permissions, and publish_stream under Extended Permissions.  Oddly enough, removing or adding publish_actions does not change the Auth Dialog.  The Extended dialog asks to "Post on your behalf".  If the user denies the Post on your behalf, I cannot use the Score API for the user.  The Score API Docs say I just need publish_actions to use the Score API.

I have two questions:
1) Does adding publish_actions change the auth dialog in any way?
2) What permission is needed in order to use the Score API?  Is it publish_actions or publish_stream?

Comment: _“Oddly enough, removing or adding publish_actions does not change the Auth Dialog.”_ – are you maybe another one who’s confusing Authenticated Referrals with requesting permissions when doing the login yourself …?

Answer (score 0):

There's been some confusion around publish_stream and publish_actions, because Facebook first [altered publish_actions](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/) to allow some overlap with publish_stream, then [made the two synonymous](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/).

1. As of now (June 2013), publish_actions does change the auth dialog,
   adding the "post on your behalf" step.
2. The permission to use from now on is publish_actions. As of now, publish_stream seems to be an alias for it, but it may be removed at some point in the future.